# Issue with join on patient name in Cerner SMART on FHIR tutorial in SmartHealthIt App Launcher

Tags: smart-on-fhir

Running the Cerner SMART on FHIR tutorial out of the box I get an unknown method Javascript error for the following lines.

```
        fname = patient.name[0].given.join(' ');
        lname = patient.name[0].family.join(' ');
```

I've currently resolved by changing to the following

```
        fname = patient.name[0].given;
        lname = patient.name[0].family;
```

What is the correct fix for this? I'm assuming the above is not a perfect work around.

Cerner tutorial is here: https://engineering.cerner.com/smart-on-fhir-tutorial/

SMART App Launcher is here: https://launch.smarthealthit.org/

Answer (score 0):

Patient.name is datatype [HumanName](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/datatypes.html#HumanName).  The family property (i.e lastname) is not an array, so calling join on it is incorrect.